# Which authority is responsible for RT licensing in the Netherlands?

Tags: pilots, radio, pilot-certification, netherlands

Which authority does issue the separate RT license for pilots in the Netherlands?

I had a conversation with Netherlands CAA and they could not help me.

Comment: Hallo Daniel, welkom to Aviation.SE

Answer (score 1):

The Dutch authority responsible for radio communication licenses is 'het agentschap telecom', part of the ministry of economic affairs.

More information about licensing for the aviation radio bands can be found on [their website](https://www.agentschaptelecom.nl/onderwerpen/luchtvaart) (in Dutch).